# Score tracker is not updating properly, what could have gone wrong?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a rock paper scissors game that plays for 5 rounds and updates the score after a round is played. The errors shows that each time I click the button random numbers are generated for the score.

```js
let player;
let computer;
let result;
let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let tieScore = 0;

const playerText = document.querySelector("#playerText");
const computerText = document.querySelector("#computerText");
const resultText = document.querySelector("#resultText");
const choiceBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".choiceBtns");
const playerScoreText = document.querySelector(".playerScoreText");
const computerScoreText = document.querySelector(".computerScoreText");
const tieScoreText = document.querySelector(".tieScoreText");

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  choiceBtns.forEach((button) =>
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
      player = button.textContent;
      computerChoice();
      playerText.textContent = `Player: ${player}`;
      computerText.textContent = `Computer: ${computer}`;
      resultText.textContent = winner();
      scoreTracker();
      playerScoreText.textContent = `Player Score: ${playerScore}`;
      computerScoreText.textContent = `Computer Score: ${computerScore}`;
      tieScoreText.textContent = `Tie Score: ${tieScore}`;
    })
  );
}

function computerChoice() {
  const randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

  switch (randNum) {
    case 1:
      computer = "Rock";
      break;
    case 2:
      computer = "Paper";
      break;
    case 3:
      computer = "Scissors";
      break;
  }
}

function winner() {
  if (player == computer) {
    return "Tie!";
  } else if (
    (player == "Rock" && computer == "Scissors") ||
    (player == "Paper" && computer == "Rock") ||
    (player == "Scissors" && computer == "Paper")
  ) {
    return "Player Wins!";
  } else {
    return "Computer Wins!";
  }
}

function scoreTracker() {
  if (winner() === "Tie!") {
    tieScore += 1;
  } else if (winner() === "Player Wins!") {
    playerScore += 1;
  } else if (winner() === "Computer Wins!") {
    computerScore += 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="gameText" id="playerText">Player:</h1>
    <h1 class="gameText" id="computerText">Computer:</h1>
    <h1 class="gameText" id="resultText">Result:</h1>

    <button class="choiceBtns">Rock</button>
    <button class="choiceBtns">Paper</button>
    <button class="choiceBtns">Scissors</button>

    <h3 class="playerScoreText">Player Score:</h3>
    <h3 class="computerScoreText">Computer Score:</h3>
    <h3 class="tieScoreText">Tie</h3>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[Here the image shows the computer wins so the score should be 1 for computer the 0 for the rest since I refreshed the website but each time I click a button the score changes randomly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAsMv.png)

Comment: Running `addEventListener` 5 times just means the event listener is added to the element 5 times, and runs 5 times for every click. If you want something to happen 5 times every time the user clicks, loop **inside** the event listener function.

Comment: I tried to do it that way but the same issue arises. If i completely remove the for loop then it seems to play round by round which is better but I need to to stop at 5.

Comment: Then just add a counter and update it in the event listener. When it reaches 5, disable the buttons.